# Ingest Azure Application Insight logs in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, stream

I am trying to ingest Azure Application Insight (Telemetry log)data in AWS.
I tried the api way, however, azure has limit on the total number of bytes that can be transferred via api call. So looking at streaming solution for Telemetry Logs from Azure AI to AWS S3.

Is there any AWS or Azure services that can be used for this implementation?

Any help is appreciated.

Tried API call and got error on the Record bytes. Apparently, Azure has a hard limit on number of bytes that can be transferred. Ofcourse, it depends on the traffic. However, considering we have a busy server, streaming is the only option. So do not know if Azure Eventhub can connect to AWS EventBridge or ay other option is available.

"error":{"code":"PartialError","message":"There were some errors when processing your query.","details":[{"code":"EngineError","message":"Something went wrong processing your query on the server.","innererror":{"code":"-2133196797","message":"The results of this query exceed the set limit of 64000000 bytes, so not all records were returned (E_QUERY_RESULT_SET_TOO_LARGE, 0x80DA0003). See
https://aka.ms/kustoquerylimits
for more information and possible solutions.","severity":2,"severityName":"Error"}}]}}'

I tried using set truncationmaxsize, but it didnt work either